# Is it possible to redirect with .htaccess based on a date in the URL for static files?

Tags: .htaccess, date, static-files

I have a group of images that should be progressively made available on specific dates in the future until the whole set is visible. The images have the date they should be visible as the file name. Anyone with a few insights into the workings of the internet could figure out the pattern in the file names and look at 'future' images before the intended date.

I'm hoping to solve this with .htaccess to prevent spinning up a script every time an image is accessed. Do you think it's possible?

The locale of the server is the only one I'm concerned about.

Thanks :)

**Edit:**

As an example, at the time of posting this message I'd want this image to serve correctly:

```
http://domain.com/images/2012-11-20.jpg
```

But I'd want this one to return a 404, 401 or whatever as it's in the future:

```
http://domain.com/images/2012-12-06.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to fully understand your question, but this link about time-dependant rewriting might give you a little push towards the right direction.

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

(I am in no way affiliated with this website!)

Comment: Hmm, thanks Jason. That looks promising. I updated the question with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the code change the `src` of the image, you could dynamically rewrite a fixed image source to the correct daily location:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /my/image.jpg
RewriteRule (.*) /images/date/%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}.jpg [L]
```

It's a bit security-by-obscurity, and you lose the ability to long-term cache the image (because come the next day, you'll want the browser to load the new image from the old path), but it might fit your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. I must apologise though, because I think my question lacked clarity (now updated). I want all the images to be available so long as they are not "for the future". Cheers :)